# error while insert data into database

Tags: c#, mysql

'Input string was not in a correct format.'

I am trying to insert data into MYSQL database using c# but I am getting error message that says

Input string was not in a correct format. I have this error when it reaches (ExecuteNonQuery).

```
    public void Register_Cutomer_Orders()
    {
        string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnSet"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdstr = @"INSERT INTO `shopsorders`
                                        (`order_id`,
                                        `Customers_customer_id`,
                                        `Employees_employee_id`,
                                        `Shops_shop_id`,
                                        `total`,
                                        `date`)
                                 VALUES
                                        (@P_order_id,
                                        @P_Customers_customer_id,
                                        @P_Employees_employee_id,
                                        @P_Shops_shop_id,
                                        @P_total,
                                        @P_date)";
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, conn))
            {

                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = cmdstr;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dGVShop.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_order_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = null;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_Customers_customer_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_Shop_ReservNum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_Employees_employee_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = 1;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_Shops_shop_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cbShop_Name.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_total", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(tb_Shop_Total.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = "sysdate()";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
                conn.Close();
            }
    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

}

Comment: Try a real Date for the Date-Parameter

Comment: If you always want sysdate in `date`  then put that in the SELECT and don't bother using a parameter for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysdate()` is not a string that can be converted to a date. If you mean to send the current time, use `DateTime.UtcNow`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

When performing implicit conversions, the database does not *execute* string tokens - it simply tries to cast it to the required type.

also: `@P_Customers_customer_id`, `@P_Shops_shop_id`, `@P_total` are all numeric, but given textual values, which is a very bad idea

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of AddWithValue is not the type of the parameter but the value.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_Customers_customer_id", TB_Shop_ReservNum.Text);
```

As you can see, this is still very weak, because you pass a string and AddWithValue decides the parameter type looking at the input received.

This blog post explain all the weakness of AddWithValue 
[Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

I prefer to use the Add method in this way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_Customers_customer_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TB_Shop_ReservNum.Text);
```

Finally, when you pass the string 'sysdate()' it will not be resolved in in the system date but in a literal string and obviously the text 'sysdate()' is not a date.

In this case you shoul use a stored procedure to get the system date on your server or pass the local computer DateTime.Now